# Get latest value of field using group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I am making a query in which i want the job ids to be grouped but i want the latest timestamp row in the result which is not happening

Here is the SQL fiddle

```
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de8769
```

The normal view for table is

[image]

The output after using this query i made

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT(user_id),
job_id,
message,
receiver_id,
parent,
type,
id as id FROM ai_ms_messages 
WHERE (receiver_id = '7' OR user_id = '7') AND type<>0 AND type<>2 group by job_id 
ORDER BY  max(timestamp) DESC
```

[image]

But as you can see its taking the value of id as 3 for job_id 11 but it should have taken the value 5 (as that is latest for job_id 11) and also the order is wrong. Since job_id 11 is latest not job_id 12. Is there any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

The query would be:

```
select 
distinct(m1.user_id),
m1.job_id,
m1.message,
m1.receiver_id,
m1.parent,
m1.type,
m1.id as id from ai_ms_messages as m1
where m1.type<>0 and m1.type<>2
and m1.timestampt = (select max(m2.timestamp) from ai_ms_messages as m2 where m2.job_id = m1.job_id)
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply. Actually i need that receiver id so i can make the condition like if user id or receiver id so that i can check if a person received or send message regarding that job. But even after removing that receiver id i am not getting the latest id

Comment: i have added it to query above

Comment: Edited. Please have a look. Besides my SQL Fiddle breaks ;)

Answer (score 0):

As per your query you are looking for data for `receiver_id = '7'` and for `id =5 , receiver_id = '6'` , so this is not in your query output.

Just remove where condition, or check data as per condition only.

GROUP BY groups on the first matching result it hits.

So, its preferable this method as the subquery.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (

SELECT DISTINCT (
user_id
), job_id, message, receiver_id, parent, 
TYPE , id AS id
FROM ai_ms_messages
WHERE (
receiver_id =  '7'
OR user_id =  '7'
)
AND TYPE <>0
AND TYPE <>2
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC
) AS sub
GROUP BY job_id
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer but it will still not show the latest id which should be 5 even if i remove  receiver id

Comment: @ParamVeer : Please check my query.

Comment: It gives problems when i try to add a fresh record for any other job type and type.